# How to return javascript variable to Ajax?

Tags: php, ajax

Does anyone know how can I return the javascript variable to ajax instead of string value while I using ajax to call the php. Please see below example for more details:

Ajax:

```
    //Ajax Param 
    var paramList = "Action=make_process";

    ajaxRequest = $.ajax({
            url: "admin.php",
            type: 'POST',
            data: paramList,
            error: function(){
                  //error message here
            },
            success: function(data){
                 //read return javascript variable here;
            }   
        });
```

PHP:

```
public function validationChk()
    {
        $error_msg['error_msg'][] = array("msg"=>"hello");
            $error_msg['error_msg'][] = array("msg"=>"hi");

        echo "var ErrorMapping = " . json_encode($error_msg). ";\n\n";          
        exit;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wondering how you can return from an AJAX response?

Then check out [this jQuery FAQ answer.](http://docs.jquery.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#How_do_I_get_and_use_the_server_response_from_an_AJAX_request.3F)

Comment: I wondering how can I passing 'var ErrorMapping' from php to ajax as variable instead of string

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do isn't all that great of an idea. What you probably want is to decode the JSON response back into an object from within your **success** callback and then return **that**.

Decoding the JSON string involves piping it through eval and hoping you don't have bad/malicious data. The safe way to do this is to parse the JSON in Javascript. If you **have** to go this route on your own then at least try to use something already written. Search Google Code for "json-sans-eval".

The better option would be to use jQuery's built-in capabilities:

```
jQuery.getJSON( url, [data], [callback] )
```

It does all the hard stuff for you. Take some time to read through jQuery's docs. There's a lot of useful stuff there.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that. In light of that fact just be sure that your data absolutely is not tainted.