# Store AJAX return into variable

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm having trouble storing an Ajax response into a variable.
Here's my code so far:

```
function bbl(phrase) {
    var lp;
    $.post(
        'babelJS.php',
        {"phrase" : phrase},
        function (data){
            lp = data.lp;
            $("#test1").html(lp);
        },
        'json'
    );
    $("#test2").html(lp);
}
```

The div `test1` is correctly field but not `test2`... Why wouldn't `lp` survive after the `$.post` section?

Thanks!

**Update** : I would also want bbl() to return lp...

**Update 2** :

I have no more luck with the following, which comes from the FAQ whose link is in the first comment to this post.

```
function getBbl(phrase,callback) {
    $.post(
        'babelJS.php',
        {"phrase" : phrase},
        function (data){
            callback(data.locphrase);
        },
        'json'
    );
}

function bbl(phrase) {
    var lp
    getBbl(phrase,function(locphrase){
        lp = locphrase;
    });
    return lp;
}
```

Comment: So many duplicates, such as [How to return javascript variable to Ajax?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/891111/how-to-return-javascript-variable-to-ajax)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the `$.post` call is asynchronous.  The .html() line is executing after the post has been sent, but the `lp = data.lp` line isn't executed until the post response is returned.

So the assignment is working fine, but it is happening too late.  To make it work, move the .html() line into the success function for the post.

Comment: Ok I understand, thanks. What if I want bbl to return lp though?

Comment: You can't.  You need to start thinking asynchronously, for example, but have bbl take a success callback, that you invoke from the post success callback.

Comment: I've just updated my post with a callback version with which I have no more luck.

Comment: If you want bbl to return lp, do a Google search for "Promises"